# Imageresizer and PrettyGifs in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, imageresizer

In previous versions of ASP.NET Core we used [PrettyGifs](https://imageresizing.net/docs/v4/plugins/prettygifs) plugin. In order to make it working we had to add  in Web.config. But in asp.net core we don't have web.config anymore. So how can we use this plugin?

Comment: Of course you have a web.config in ASP.NET Core, but it's only used as entry point for IIS to know where the app is located and how to start it. You can't use it to store configuration files etc. Not sure what you mean with "previous versions of ASP.NET Core", but PrettyGifs  doesn't seem to support .NET Core so if you can/manage to use it with ASP.NET Core you can only target .NET Framework 4.x with it - Which you should consider twice, as ASP.NET Core 2.0 preview1 almost deprecated .NET Framework support...

Comment: ...and chances are that .NET Framework support may be removed in future (3.0, 4.0, etc.) since it moves much slower than .NET Core

Answer (score 1):

All plugins also offer code-based configuration/installation, like `new PrettyGifs().Install(Config.Current);`

That said, ImageResizer 4.X requires .NET Full for the moment. [Imageflow](https://github.com/imazen/imageflow) will support .Net Core and is cross-platform.